# why did my text box value not getting in action Class using struts? i am getting password field's value but not of text field

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts, jsp-tags, jspinclude

this is my action class, i hv properly defined struts.xml,
   My problem is that,
   i am getting textBox Username value NULL, but other inputs are returning the value.
   I Am Adding User.java class, Struts ActionClass.

```
public class UserLogin extends ActionSupport {
User user = new User();
public String getAccess() {  
  System.out.println(user.getPassword()+"and"+user.getUserName()); 
 // output: xyz and null
  if (user.getPassword().equals("pass")){
    System.out.println(user.getUserName());
            return "success";
} else{
    return "input";
}
}

public User getModel() {

return user;
}
}
```

And My **jsp** Page is:

```
<form action="login">
UserName:<input type="text" name="userName"/>
Password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="login"/>
</form>
```

**User.java**

```
public User {

private String userName;
private String password;

public String getUserName(){
return userName;
} 
public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
public String getPassword(){
return password;
} 
public void setPassword(String password) {
this.password= password;
}
}
```

Comment: where did u collected username and password show that file. means user file code??

Comment: Please post your User class also.

Comment: Is this ur complete code? if this is your complete user code then what did u for password?

Comment: public String getUserName() { why this line in your code?

Comment: yeah, its my simple code, for user login only, i am not getting only textbox value, all other input tags are returning value properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1265684/dev- sorry, i posted my class method in comments mistakely, i have removed them...

Comment: in user file  why this?     public String getUserName() {

Comment: sorry, i have edited it, now this is the final code,

Comment: ok,it seems ok every thing.

Comment: if i changes input type 'text' to any other like password, radio or textbox, it is returning proper value,

Comment: use jsp form instead of html form wail a minute for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Jsp taglib` for taking user input
 use the following JSp form put this code in your `login.jsp` file.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>LogIn</title>
</head>

<body>
<s:form action="login" method="get">
 <s:textfield name="userName" key="Username" size="20" />
<s:password name="password"  key="Password" size="20" />
<s:submit method="getAccess" align="center"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

if following line

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
```

give error then download jsp tag lib jar and put in your lib folder.

Comment: thanks dear...... :) but if we dont want to use struts tag, in that case wh would we get value ?

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-el/index.html read this carefully..

Answer (score 1):

Define properties `userName` and `password` and their getter and setter methods in your action.

Just use `getUserName()` and `getPassword()` instead of `user.getUserName()` and `user.getPassword()`.

Action form can read the values submitted in the browser with these properties. Those properties you have to assign to the `user` object and then you can use them from `user` object.

Comment: but dear, hw i m getting passwrd, textbox, radio etc exclude textbox input value in return ???????

Comment: In that case, you need to check `getModel` method. Also as @dev suggested, use struts tags instead of HTML tags.